# How can I find a user's group using AD authentication in aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

So I followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx) tutorial and I can successfully login, but now I was trying to find out if a user belongs to a group, I've tried:

```
if (User.IsInRole("group"))
```

along with

```
enableSearchMethods="true"
```

Nothing seems to work though, perhaps I'm looking at the wrong place... Anyone has any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....
   PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

   // enumerate the groups found - check to find your group in question
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Alternatively, you can also find the user and the group principals:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");
GroupPrincipal groupToCheck = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

if(user != null && groupToCheck != null)
{
    // this call will tell you - yes or no - whether that user is member of that group
    bool isMember = user.IsMemberOf(groupToCheck); 
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, if the user's Windows is already logged into the domain with their respective username can I read that information easily?

Comment: @Pedro'Xympa'Nascimento: sure - just use `UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current` to get the current user

Comment: Not working when I publish it, this exception is thrown: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.